# How to remove lines before the keyword and up to its match string tag

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
Sample text1 <TAG> some text
Line1
Line2
<INSERT>
Sample text3 <TAG> some text
Line3
<DELETE>
Sample text4 <TAG> some text
Line4
Line5
<INSERT>
Sample text5 <TAG> some text
Line6
<DELETE>
```

I want to remove the lines before the DELETE and up to the TAG so that it will look like this:

```
Sample text1 <TAG> some text
Line1
Line2
<INSERT>
Sample text4 <TAG> some text
Line4
Line5
<INSERT>
```

Comment: Take the solutions you were given to your previous question and change the keywords from `START` and `END` to `TAG` and `DELETE`. Note: I only tested my solution and it worked.

Comment: @JamesBrown, yeah this becomes exact duplicate when you put it like that.. at first I thought OP wanted to delete from line immediately after `<INSERT>` upto and including `<DELETE>`

Comment: @JamesBrown It is different from my previous question. My problem here is in the TAG because all insert, delete, update has the same starting tag. So I cannot use sed '/TAG/,/DELETE/d' because it will delete the line1 to 5.

Comment: @Bootsector Like I said, you can use my solution of your previous question to solve this one, also. If the problem is really different, maybe you should emphasize that in the question - along with showing what you did to try to solve the problem in your question.

Comment: @JamesBrown Sorry, I did not notice your answer on my previous question. Yes,  your solution is really working. Thank you!

Comment: @Bootsector, `tac ip.txt | sed '/<DELETE>/,/<TAG>/d' | tac` would work for this case too.. can you highlight what goes wrong? that way this question can be modified and not closed as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In awk using my previous solution mentioned in comments:

```
$ cat foo.awk
/TAG/ { printf "%s", b; b="" }                       # at START output buffer and empty it
{ b=b $0 ORS }                                       # gather buffer
/DELETE/ { b="" }                                    # at empty buffer at END also
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk foo2
Sample text1 <TAG> some text
Line1
Line2
<INSERT>
Sample text4 <TAG> some text
Line4
Line5
<INSERT>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'p&&/<TAG>/{p=0;next} !p&&/<TAG>/{p=1}p' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk 'p&&/<TAG>/{p=0;next} !p&&/<TAG>/{p=1}p' file
Sample text1 <TAG> some text
Line1
Line2
<INSERT>
Sample text4 <TAG> some text
Line4
Line5
<INSERT>
```